# Are there any tricks for using an oscillating multitool?

Tags: tools, powertools

[image]

I recently got myself a [Ridgid JobMax](http://www.ridgid.com/Tools/R82234-Kit/EN/index.htm) and I think I love it. I did spend quite a bit of time, however, trying to get through an old (100 year old home) 2x4 (dimensional). I don't know if the wood was just really hard or if I am just not good at using the tool yet. I did watch some YouTube videos and started using more of a sweeping motion with the cutting blade and that helped. I'm just wondering if anyone else has any good tips or experience using this tool that would be helpful to me.

Comment: A rocking motion seems to help.

Comment: I would bet that part of the problem is that the old wood really is a lot stronger.  I was blown away at how quickly I would go through reciprocating saw blades when cutting through the original walls at my house (85 years old).

Comment: Agreed w/ auujay and Evil Greebo -- old wood can be almost petrified; I burn through drillbits, saw blades, etc, for a house that was ~60 years old when I bought it.  (2x4s are ~1.75"x3.75", except for two additions)

Comment: I agree with the consensus that your 100 year old 2x4 was probably hard as a rock. But it's worth keeping in mind that of all the cool things these tools can do (aside from the name I love my Rockwell SoniCrafter too), cutting quickly isn't one of them. The small-stroke oscillating motion and those tiny triangular gear teeth just can't remove material like a "real" saw blade with raked teeth and kerf.

Comment: I also have a Rockwell and love it. Don't know how I got to this point in life without it. LOL.  Old wood can be very hard and takes a while to work thru. Also be sure you are using the most aggressive blade possible. A fine blade will dull quickly and take forever.

Comment: [Related](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/86718/multi-cutter-blade-blunt-in-1-day-bad-blade-bad-technique): Multi-cutter blade blunt in 1 day. Bad blade? Bad Technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you, I find it more effective as a cutter through harder surfaces if you move the blade across the surface you wish to cut.  I also apply light pressure to the tool while "sawing" with it.

Although in your case, it probably was simply that the wood was very hard.